# When i use 'func(){myFunc()}' in cron.AddFunc() in golang cron, the output is not as expected

Tags: go

```
func main() {
    c := cron.New()
    tcs := []testCron{testCron1, testCron2}
    for _, t := range tcs {
        spec, _ := t()
        c.AddFunc(spec, func() { t() })
    }
    c.Start()
    select {}
}
type testCron func() (string, error)
func testCron1() (string, error) {
    fmt.Println("testCron1")
    return "@every 5s", nil
}

func testCron2() (string, error) {
    fmt.Println("testCron2")
    return "@every 5s", nil
}
```

output:
testCron1
testCron2
testCron2
testCron2
testCron2
testCron2
testCron2
expect:
testCron1
testCron2
testCron1
testCron2
testCron1
testCron2
testCron1
testCron2
testCron1
testCron2

Comment: `func() { t() }` refers to the `t` loop variable which is overwritten in each iteration.

Comment: thx，it can run properly when i add a temporary variable to ```t```